# Why is my beta/dev site considered unhealthy for not allowing indexing?

Tags: google-search-console

I don't want beta.example.com indexed, so I've set robots.txt to disallow all crawling and lodged a removal request for the whole domain, which is no longer seen as pending.

For some reason, Google considers this to be "severe health issues". Are there further problems? Is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: Please add this image to the question if you have enough rep: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nd0s.png

Comment: Did you want to disable crawling for example.com or for beta.example.com?

Comment: @Catcall beta.example.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Google Webmaster Tools exists to help you to improve your site's visibility on Google -- it's not a general purpose website console. In that context, disallowing all crawling is indeed a "severe health issue", as it means that your site is not visible on Google at all. Since that's what you wanted, the solution is simply to stop worrying about it.